# Strapi GraphQL - Sort by items count subquery

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, strapi

I have the following GraphQL query:

```
query {
  tags(limit: 9) {
    id
    tag
    items {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, `items` is a collection of values. I'd like to sort this collection by `items` count; each `tag` can have multiple `items`.

I couldn't find any example/documentation about this case, any idea?